# How to fix app store Mountain Lion download that stops at 45%?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, data-transfer

I have tried to download Mountain Lion from the app store only to have it show up in my dock and begin "downloading". Except it never completes the download. Each time I begin the download again, it gets a bit farther, but after about 45% it won't download any more data, even after waiting 12 hours. My Mac is most definitely compatible and my colleagues on the same model/version of the machine I am using have downloaded and installed Mountain Lion without any issues.

I have:

- Repaired permissions
- Installed all the most recent Mac updates for Snow Leopard
- Restarted the computer
- Cleared my App Store cache

No error messages, just won't complete the download. I'm afraid if I call Apple for help they will charge me for a product I have paid for, but doesn't work.

How to completely download Mountain Lion from the app store?

Comment: does your Mac goes to sleep this time? have you tried pause/resume? have you tried cancel download (press alt on purchases screen)?

Answer (score 1):

I spoke to the Apple Store, and it had to do with a faulty harddrive which came out in my model. I went through the Hard Drive Replacement Program, and all went well, with Mountain Lion installed.